# How can I convert a string quarter year to a timestamp in Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, databricks

In Databricks SQL, how can I convert a date in string format `"2021Q2"` to a timestamp with the last day of that quarter?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/last_day.html and use left & right for your year and month.  You'll need to either multiply the qtr * 3 or change to 3,6,9,12 in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    to_timestamp(
       last_day(
          to_date(
            (left('2021Q4',4)||'-'||int(right('2021Q4',1)*3))||'-'||'1'))) 
from 
   my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a pity that Q is not working in formatting from string to date object (it is working only in reverse) - parsing Q with to_date(date, "YYYY'QQ")  sadly will not work.

According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html:
*Symbols of ‘E’, ‘F’, ‘q’ and ‘Q’ can only be used for datetime formatting, e.g. date_format. They are not allowed used for datetime parsing, e.g. to_timestamp.*

Because of that we have to separate quarter and multiple by 4. Than convert it to date object (parse_ and take last_date of the month:

```
SELECT
 last_day(
    to_date(
      concat(left("2021Q4", 4), int(right("2021Q4", 1))*3),
      "yyyyMM")
  ) as last_day_of_quarter
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way :

```
select to_timestamp(last_day(concat('2021','-',0,4*3,'-01'))) as last_date_queter
```

Logic :

- calculate the last month of quarter by using multiple with 3. example 4th quarter's last month calculated `12 (4*3)`
- `concat (year,'-',-01)` so that we can get the first day of respective month `2021-12-01`
- `last_day` we can use last date of the given date month.
- finally , we can convert the date into timestamp `to_timestamp`

[image]